# Send request after checkout process in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I've an e-commerce website powered by Magento but now I need to make the connection bewteen Magento and the company's management software.

The process should be this:

1. The user put some stuff in his cart
2. The user go through the checkout process
3. After the user have paid the total with Paypal, Magento should send an HTTP request (perhaps POST, with order's data) to an external server that handles the request and do stuff with the data received.

My problem is that I've no idea how to send a request from Magento with the order data after the checkout process. I think this is a common scenario for companies that uses e-commerce. Do you have some ideas for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a observer to get the after checkout event, and on your observer you can send some kind of curl post to your external server. (Like @Prasath Albert said)

Take a look there to make a observer: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

You are looking for checkout_cart_save_after. Good lucky, let me know if you need something else.

Edit:

Use this tutorial to do your Observer http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method make 100% like this. Create new module to do it.

Then your observer method can be something like that:

```
function observermethod($observer){
    $observer->getEvent->getOrder()->getData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Should I use CURL or is there a better way?

Comment: You can use Curl or Httprequest or any other libary what do http request. Or you can use some other PHP functions to send informations. Look http request example: http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php

Comment: checkout_cart_save_after is not the good event, it will be called each time the cart is updated. Prefer sales_order_payment_pay (+optionnal check if paypal method) or sales_order_place_after

Comment: @Bixi, i don't have sure about what event is better in this case, but any way you can take a look on event list and try some http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/

Comment: So Fred you can trust on @Bixi ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Anyway I'm a Magento newbie, could someone give me a simple example of how to do that? Also, where can I find all order information like customer's information and products information? You're great

Comment: That tutorial is updated? Because at the beginning is written: "
Note for recent versions of Magento - Broken
Seems like this tutorial doesn’t work anymore for recent versions (1.6.2 for me), because of magento prices indexing. Price is not calculated on the fly on frontend anymore, and indexing does not call the event “catalog_product_get_final_price”. To be confirmed."

Answer (score 1):

you can use the CURL to achieve this. for this

1) Add a page in the external server for handling the inputs from the magento.

2) Edit the Magento Cart functionality, to send a request to the External server.

Ex: you can use the CURL to make this request.

```
   $data = "item=".$item;//input data
   $url="http://External server/handler.php";
   $handle = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   curl_exec($handle);
```

Comment: Where's placed the Magento Cart functionatily?